# How to hide Wi-Fi info

Tags: network, wifi

How to hide the Wi-Fi info from the people who are connected to my Wi-Fi?

Comment: what info do you want to hide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Wifi routers come with a 'guest' network option to enable. This sets up a type of DMZ that gives people access to your wifi but limits, and with things like VLAN and completely separate sub-netting, changes the information they can see about your network so that it would be completely different than your actual network. For instance, your local wifi is on 192.168.x.x and your guest network is on 10.0.x.x so there would be no way for them to swim up stream to see other info about your actual network.

Answer (score -2):

We assume you are looking the ways to hide your Access Point Name from being listed on users' devices?

You can set Hide Access Point Name (SSID broadcast OFF) on your Access Point so potential users who don't know your access point name will not see it on their devices.

Comment: OP asked "people who are connected to my Wi-Fi" - so hiding the SSID doesn't make a lot of sense.